# How to find the values of a complex function on either side of a branch cut?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, branch-cuts, branch-points

I have the complex function $f(z)=(z^2+1)^{1/2}$ which had branch point singularities at z=i, z=-i.

To try to find the value of $f$ on either side of the cut I considered $z=i+\epsilon e^{i\theta}$, which gives

$f=(2i\epsilon e^{i\theta}+\epsilon ^2 e^{2i\theta})^{1/2}$.

I then let $\theta --> \theta +2\pi$. I was hoping I would then see a nice factor come out of the expression for $f$ to see how it changes. But i get

$f=(\epsilon e^{i\theta+\pi}+\epsilon ^2 e^{2i\theta + 4\pi})^{1/2}$

and I don't know what to do with this...

Perhaps I am missing something obvious or made a silly error, or maybe my approach is completely wrong?

Comment: You should first define the domain of $f$. One possible choice is $\mathbb C\setminus [-i,i]$.

Comment: @YiorgosS.Smyrlis Yes, I should have statef the branch cut that I took. It was indeed the straight line along the imaginary axis from -i to i. However I am still not sure how to find the change in f on either side of the branch cut, despite having been stating at the problem for the last couple of days...